# How do I destroy a class/how do I link a class to a gameObject

Tags: unity, pong

I am fairly new to programming and I decided to create a Pong game. I created the sprites and was able to make the paddles and the dot work. The only help I needed was when I wanted the dot to recognize where it was hit.

Now I wanted to respawn the dot when it hits an wall behind the racket. I created an transparent sprite with a 2D Collider. Now I wanted to use this:

If dot hits LeftWall destroy gameobject dot

But when I use:

```
 if (col.gameObject.name == "WandLinks")
    {
      Destroy(Dot.gameObject);
    }
```

it tells me "Dot" is a class and can't be destroyed. This I understand. But why does the rest work? And how do I create a reference from the class to a new gameObject? Thank you very much.

(My next solution is to place the code for the destruction inside my wall but that's not my desired solution)

-
This is my whole code for the dot

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dot : MonoBehaviour

{
public float speed = 5;
public Transform spawnPoint;

void Start()
{
    // Initial Velocity
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
}

float hitFactor(Vector2 ballPos, Vector2 racketPos,
                float PaddleRight)
{
    // ascii art:
    // ||  1 <- at the top of the racket
    // ||
    // ||  0 <- at the middle of the racket
    // ||
    // || -1 <- at the bottom of the racket
    return (ballPos.y - racketPos.y) / PaddleRight;
}
public void RespawnDot()
{
    Instantiate(dot, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    // Note: 'col' holds the collision information. If the
    // Ball collided with a racket, then:
    //   col.gameObject is the racket
    //   col.transform.position is the racket's position
    //   col.collider is the racket's collider

    // Hit the left Racket?
    if (col.gameObject.name == "PaddleLeft")
    {
        // Calculate hit Factor
        float y = hitFactor(transform.position,
                            col.transform.position,
                            col.collider.bounds.size.y);

        // Calculate direction, make length=1 via .normalized
        Vector2 dir = new Vector2(1, y).normalized;

        // Set Velocity with dir * speed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;
    }

    // Hit the right Racket?
    if (col.gameObject.name == "PaddleRight")
    {
        // Calculate hit Factor
        float y = hitFactor(transform.position,
                            col.transform.position,
                            col.collider.bounds.size.y);

        // Calculate direction, make length=1 via .normalized
        Vector2 dir = new Vector2(-1, y).normalized;

        // Set Velocity with dir * speed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;
    }

    if (col.gameObject.name == "WandRechts")
    {
        RespawnDot();
    }

    if (col.gameObject.name == "WandLinks")
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your Dot Gameobject in the game? Get the reference to that on Destroy it.

Comment: That basically is my question :D How do I create a reference to my class or the sprite I am using? 

Everything I wrote worked fine; I though it created the reference as I placed the script inside my sprite.

Comment: You sure that's all your code? I don't see `dot` being defined (referenced in `RespawnDot()`). If you want to destroy the current `Dot` just call `Destroy(this);`.

Comment: Nono, the dot part isn't all mine as I said. Thats where I needed help with. Destroy(this) didn't work. But "Destroy(gameObject). Didnt know that Unity created this reference by itself. 

Problem now is:

public void RespawnDot()
    {
        Instantiate(gameObject, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);

    }

When I instantiate the dot it spawns but doesn't move as before. How do I move the object afterwards? Thats the last question - after that the game is complete. Sorry for bothering too much :/

Comment: It likely doesn't move because the script isn't present on the new copy. Why this is we can't determine through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I use to destroy my objects: 
GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);

Comment: Thank you for help MrDrProfessor :) 
But when I try this it tells me "Dot" is a class and can't be destroyed. How do I turn my class into a gameObject?

Comment: In Unity you can drag your scripts onto the game objects in the scene or use add component in the inspector. Have you tried replacing the line of code "Destroy(Dot.gameObject);" to "GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);"?

Comment: Ah! If I drag the script onto the object it basically creates a reference with "gameObject" being the reference?

Comment: @Redgrieve *`Dot is a class...`* Yes, you need to destroy the *instance.* And in this instance (pun intended) that instance is `this`. And as you actually want to destroy the GO that the script is attached to, this answer is correct.